# Java concurrency visibility

Tags: java, concurrency, visibility

I have a question about visibility in java. The visibility can only appear if we have at least two threads, which run on at least 2 cpu cores . It that right ? Every core can cache variables in its regiresters and cache memory and because of that visibility problems can appear. But what if we have n threads and they all run in one cpu core (of couse, we can not be sure that they will run on only 1 core, but assume that it is possible to achieve that), than there is no way to have memory visibility ? Or this is not right ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by memory visibility?

Comment: One thread to change variable and other thread don't seeing this change. Sorr, if I didn't use the right termin.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I have to ask: what difference does it make? If you learned that multi-threaded programs running on a single-core machine won't be affected by concurrency bugs the same way they would when run on multiple cores, would you go ahead and write buggy code? I don't know enough about processors and JVM implementation, to say, but even in a single core, it seems like data  fetched from main memory to a cache could be invalidated before it's read, thus creating a visibility problem on one core.

Comment: I want to know that, because this will help me to understand how it works. My code will not depend on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by visibility you refer to shared memory, so that objects that are created or altered in one thread may be visible in another thread, then it does not matter how many cores there are, the visibility will remain the same.  Java makes promises as per the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html), specifically the [Java Memory Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_memory_model),  that must be followed regardless of how many cores.

> But what if we have n threads and they all run in one cpu core (of couse, we can not be sure that they will run on only 1 core, but assume that it is possible to achieve that), than there is no way to have memory visibility ? Or this is not right ?

Yes the visibility (shared memory) still exists if there are n threads running on one core.  But there are some caveats that exist regardless of how many core.  Mainly that each thread has its own cached memory and a variable may have different values across both threads.  If the variable is `volatile`, then the value of that variable will always get updated across all threads.

> A field may be declared volatile, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable (§17.4).

I recommend you read up more on the Java Memory Model.

Comment: Actually, I didn't think about that every thread has its own cache, not only different cores. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

Even on 1 core running multiple threads, you can still have what you are calling this "visibility" problem, as threads that have loaded a value from memory into a register will save this value to that thread's stack, and will not see the update if the thread is switched off then switched back on again *unless* the variable / memory is declared `volatile`

Comment: "Visibility" is the common term, used in the Java Language Specification and elsewhere.

Comment: And can you give an example of an update on the stack that is visible to another thread? There are only local variables, which are confined to the stack, and fields, which are in the heap, so I don't understand what updates you mean.

Comment: The low-level implementation of threading may leave some variables not strictly on the stack or the heap.  They may be stored in registers that are only visible to the thread.  The point is you really don't know, and should assume that concurrency requires the appropriate synchronization, rather than make assumptions about your execution environment.

Comment: Something like a "native" stack frame? That makes sense.